# Why we can't deglaze with oil/butter?

Tags: meat, searing, deglazing

I was cooking chicken soup today. Everything happens in a medium-size dutch oven. I've started with browning some meat in olive oil, then removed it, and added butter and onion to caramelize.

I tried to scrape all the brown bits from the bottom while onions were cooking in the butter, and had trouble. But when i added a splash of chicken stock, it immediately lifted all browned bits with minimal scraping.

What is the mechanism of that difference? Why can't oil/butter lift brown bits?

Comment: See: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/117261/how-does-deglazing-work

Comment: This feels like a duplicate of that question.